# GIMP tooltips are almost unreadable white-on-off-white

Tags: kde, gtk, gimp

Running GIMP on my KDE desktop the tooltips are all white-on-white.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Appears to be a special case of https://superuser.com/questions/1100408/tooltips-of-gtk-applications-are-unreadable-within-kde, but the solution given here is easier, though maybe uglier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **quote** [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1286452/571648) by [Narcolessico](https://superuser.com/users/844027/narcolessico) to the generalisation of this question on Super User, i.e. https://superuser.com/questions/1100408/tooltips-of-gtk-applications-are-unreadable-within-kde:

> The issue is due to a partial override of GTK colors by means of KDE style.
>
> Open `System Settings > Colors`, deselect `Apply colors to non-Qt applications`, restart the GTK application (e.g. Gimp). This breaks the feeling that all applications share the same style but tooltips will be again readable in both Qt and GTK applications.

This solution leaves the rest of Gimp looking much the same, while [Matthew Cline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/41033/matthew-cline)’s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446090/199532) here (use high contrast Gtk themes) makes Gimp look (in my eyes) pretty clunky.

Anyone wanting fine-grained control should probably use https://superuser.com/a/1190633/571648, which tells you which configuration files to edit, though their location seems to be different on my installation.

Comment: It is `Apply colours to non-KDE4 applications` in my case (KDE4.14 on CentOS 7.7).

Answer (score 1):

Go to [KDE system settings](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/systemsettings/using-kapp.html), then pick **Application Style**, then pick **GNOME Application Style (GTK)**.  For both `Select a GTK2 Theme` and `Select a GTK3 Theme` choose `HighContrast`, then click on `Apply`.

Comment: Many thanks; it makes the tootips readable but is pretty ugly. I might look into defining it oneself, but for now perhaps I shall just live with it.